# Coldfusion - subdir include not seeing application variables

Tags: coldfusion

I'm very confused by something I ran into today. This is running on linux ColdFusion 8 server. I have an index page in the root that includes a 'header.cfm' file in a subdirectory ('header/header.cfm'). Variables that are set in Application.cfc are not being seen in header.cfm.

```
/myRoot  
    |- Application.cfc  
    |- index.cfm  
    /header  
        |-header.cfm
```

Application.cfc

```
OnRequestStart: <cfset myAppPath = '/myRoot'>
```

index.cfm has this line:

```
<cfinclude template="header/header.cfm">
```

header/header.cfm

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='#myAppPath#/styles/style.css'>
```

When I run index.cfm, I get this error: "myAppPath" is undefined.

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  cfdump your variables scope right before your cfinclude tag and then again as the first line on header.cfm.  Look for differences.

Comment: Try putting myAppPath in the request.scope =  <cfset request.myAppPath = '/myRoot'>

Comment: Set the variable in onRequest(), not onRequestStart(). Pages within your app can see variables only when they are defined in onRequest(), unless you are using a shared scope.

Comment: OnRequest() worked, thanks. BKK.. I think that's what you were trying to say also.

Comment: @imthepitts:  "Pages within your app can see variables only when they are defined in onRequest()" that's not quite right. It's because when using `onRequest()` one is including the template being called, so it's running in the context of the Application.cfc. And unscoped variables set in Application.cfc are just in the variables scope of the CFC instance: which will be the variables scope the included file uses, but which is gone by the time the requested file is actually executed if *not* included in `onRequest()`.